# Why aren't my document pages in order?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm working on a 53 page Word document and just noticed that my page ordering goes 1,2,... 29, 30, 1, 1, 2, 3, ..., 20, 21!
This is confirmed in the TOC at the start after updating all my fields:

[image]

I have recently added a new landscape page using this guide: https://www.lifewire.com/insert-landscape-page-into-portrait-document-3540353

I think this adds an additional section but the page numbers should be document-wide, shouldn't they?

I've also noticed odd behaviour that my keyboard cursor can jump dozens of pages at times when I press the down arrow. I'm not sure if there's something fundamentally wrong in the document but it's certainly not how I want it to work!

Comment: no, pages are section-wise, for example many books have a TOC (and maybe also the appendix) that's numbered differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Go to each section with a problem and format the pages to continue from previous.

Formatted page numbering is by section. You can display section information in your status bar.

You could use your current TOC hyperlinks to get to the problem sections.

1. Click on an entry to jump to the page that is restarting at 1.
2. Insert > Page Number > [Format Page Numbers](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#FormatPageNumbers)
3. Tell Word to continue numbering in that section from the previous section
4. Use `Alt+Left Arrow` to return to your TOC and repeat as necessary.
5. Update your TOC

Here is a [link to my free Add-In that makes all page numbering continuous](https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ContinuousPageNumbering) in a Word document. Here is a [link to information about page numbering](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers) in my chapter on Sections.

---

*My guess as to how this happened is that you have some front matter and wanted your numbering to start after that front matter. You added a section so you could restart numbering. Later, you added additional sections. Those repeat that start at one page formatting.*

*Changing orientation, margins, or columns on some pages adds section breaks.*

Answer (score 0):

This might be a quick fix:

1. Hold down CTRL and press A to select everything in the document. (CTRL+A)
2. Look under the "Layout" tab and check under "Line Numbers."
3. Select "None" and make sure "Restart Each Section" isn't selected.
4. Navigate back to the "Insert" tab and add Page Numbers back.

[image]

If "Restart Each Section" was selected it means that there is a "Section Break" in the document where the the page numbers reset. On the "Home" tab you can turn on/off formatting symbols to see them and delete them.  It looks like the backwards "P" icon on the bar.

[image]

> "I've also noticed odd behaviour that my keyboard cursor can jump
> dozens of pages at times when I press the down arrow."

A few things can happen to make this occur:

1. If you're using a wireless keyboard, check your batteries.  When these start to go out you'll get weird behavior of input seemingly coming in "bursts" that could replicate this behavior.
2. Up and Down arrow keys are always relative to where your cursor is currently in the document.  If you clicked on page 2 somewhere and then scrolled down to page 10, then used the down arrow key the view window would snap back up to page 2 where your cursor is and move you down 1 line.
3. Less commonly a workstation under load can exhibit input lag.  This happens to me when I'm ripping video from a DVD or rendering video... or any activity that runs up my processor utilization to 100% for a period of time.

Comment: the keyboard jump is always between the same places in the document. For instance I have 3 blank lines on page 10, I delete them and suddenly I'm on page 50. If I hit ctrl+z, I jump back to page 10 where the last change was. THis might be a separate question once I resolve sections though,